# Entity Framework Code First 0 to 1 mapping

Tags: c#, .net, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I want to create a map of these 2 models, how do I do this in code-first?

```
public class Payment
{
    public int PaymentId { get; set; }
}

public class PaymentBank
{
    public int PaymentId { get; set; }
}

public class PaymentCheque
{
    public int PaymentId { get; set; }
}
```

`Payment` can be either of type `PaymentBank` or `PaymentCheque`. I'm trying to follow a scenario like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312006/what-database-schema-can-i-use-to-save-different-types-of-billing-data/312144#312144). I'd love if I could do inheritance of this if possible, such as:

```
public class PaymentCheque : Payment
{
    public int RoutingNumber {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Check this article about inheritance in code first: [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx)

Comment: Btw. if you do not plan to add any additional Payment types I would recommend using TPH strategy because other strategies have worse performance.

Comment: @Ladislav, I want to add more as the client requests more payment options. Does this mean I should use TPC?

Comment: I like the 1 table per heriachy, and it seems it will work well in my situation. What other scenarios would TPC makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out the following three articles which focus on implementing inheritance in Entity Framework Code-First:
http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx
http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx
http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Did you actualy try it? Or search/google for it?

see: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx