# ERD: how to store data for three different payment types

Tags: mysql, database-normalization, erd, rdbms

Let’s say a user has 3 different ways for payment. Cash, IBAN, and through providing certain_document. Each payment type requires its own different details.

How can I store this in my database?

Let’s say the user has chosen to pay using his IBAN, assuming [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/336uM.jpg) is the current database, do I fill the fields associated with the IBAN option and set the others to Null? Or is there a more professional way to store the data without having these Null values?

**UPDATE**

I found a solution to this problem in the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312006/what-database-schema-can-i-use-to-save-different-types-of-billing-data), however, the answer is still not sufficient. If anybody has a link to a more detailed documents please let me know.

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. (Obviously.) Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained.

Comment: Thank you @philipxy If you have any other questions that you might think are a possible duplicate of my question please let me know. Thanks again.

Comment: There are a zillion [so] & [dba.se] duplicates & other resources online, google database/sql subtyping/supertyping/inheritance/polymorphism. See the dozens of  textbooks free online re how various information modeling methods deal with subtyping in designs & databases.

Answer (score 0):

As @philipxy noted, you're asking about representing inheritance in a RDBMS. There are a few different ways to do this:

1. Have all of your attributes in one table (which, based on your screenshot, is what you have now). With this approach, it would be best to store `NULL`s in non-applicable columns---if nothing else, the default settings for InnoDB tables uses the compact row format, which means NULL columns don't take up extra storage. Of course, your queries can get complex, and maintaining these tables can become cumbersome.
2. Have child tables to store your details:

   - `Payments (PaymentID, PaymentDate, etc.)`
   - `CashPaymentDetails(PaymentID, Cash_Detail_1, Cash_Detail_2, etc.)`
   - `IBANPaymentDetails(PaymentID, IBAN_Detail_1, etc.)`
   - You can get the information for each payment by joining the base payment table with one of the "subsidiary" tables:

     `SELECT *
     FROM Payments P INNER JOIN CashPaymentDetails C ON 
      C.PaymentID = P.PaymentID`
3. Your third option is to use the entity-attribute-value (EAV) model. Like with Option 2, you have a base Payment table. However, instead of having one table for each payment method, you have one subsidiary table that contains the payment details. For more information, [here's the Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), and [here's a blog](https://sqlblog.org/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway) with some additional information.